# What is the keystore password?

Tags: android, facebook, key, facebook-android-sdk

I am using android facebook sdk to have a login functionality in my app. I know how to generate a key hash(it's command actually) but I don't know what password do I need to give it, everytime I enter a new password it get's me the key. Is there any specific password? How do I get that password? Also, I am getting an error continuously that no key hash matches with the key hash that is printed on the screen(in the error). Why is that happening?

Comment: Have you looked at the documents at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/  They include information about the command to run  keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Comment: ^That asks me a password.

Comment: That is probably the password for your machine.

Comment: Nopes, that's not. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass your key store password,keystore which you are using for sign in the app.If application is not live i mean directly running from eclipse debug keystore password("android") need to pass. –